# What am I doing wrong with this SSRS switch expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am following the guide here -> 
[How to Add Excel-like "color scale" red-yellow-green conditional formatting in SSRS report based on min and max values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861072/how-to-add-excel-like-color-scale-red-yellow-green-conditional-formatting-in-s)
and using the following code from the answer

```
 =SWITCH 
(Fields!.Value >= Min(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName") + (5 *((Max(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName")-Min(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName"))/6)) ,"#0ca102"
 Fields!.Value >= Min(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName") + (4 *((Max(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName")-Min(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName"))/6)) ,"#7fda24"
 Fields!.Value >= Min(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName") + (3 *((Max(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName")-Min(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName"))/6)),"#bdff30"
 Fields!.Value >= Min(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName") + (2 *((Max(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName")-Min(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName"))/6)),"Gold"
 Fields!.Value >= Min(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName") + ((Max(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName")-Min(Fields!myField.Value, "DataSetName"))/6),"Yellow"
 1=1,"Coral")
```

Then I replaced the names of the variable with my actual names, but I think I missed up somewhere along the way because my report doesn't run. Does anyone see what I did wrong?

This is my version

```
=SWITCH 
 (Min(Fields!NEValue.Value, "CustomersByState") >= Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState") + (5 * ((Min(Fields!NYValue.Value, "CustomersByState")-Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState"))/6)) ,"#0ca102"
 Min(Fields!NEValue.Value, "CustomersByState") >= Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState") + (4  * ((Min(Fields!NYValue.Value, "CustomersByState")-Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState"))/6)) ,"#7fda24"
 Min(Fields!NEValue.Value, "CustomersByState") >= Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState") + (3  * ((Min(Fields!NYValue.Value, "CustomersByState")-Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState"))/6)),"#bdff30"
 Min(Fields!NEValue.Value, "CustomersByState") >= Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState") + (2  * ((Min(Fields!NYValue.Value, "CustomersByState")-Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState"))/6)),"Gold"
 Min(Fields!NEValue.Value, "CustomersByState") >= Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState") + ((Min(Fields!NYValue.Value, "CustomersByState")-Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState"))/6),"Yellow"
 1=1,"Coral")
```

EDIT: This is not a duplicate question, the previous question was asking how to get the number to the polygon, this question is only about the case statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS Switch statement in Expression is not working (color code a polygon in a chart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895055/ssrs-switch-statement-in-expression-is-not-working-color-code-a-polygon-in-a-ch)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it is a completely separate question...

Comment: report doesn't run is pretty vague! What error message do you get? I don't know what the 1=1 is doing.. you can simply use Coral as the default case.. so would be just "Yellow","Coral") at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the comma after your hex colors. It goes like

```
=Switch(Condition1, TruePart1, Condition2, TruePart2, ...)

=SWITCH(
        Min(Fields!NEValue.Value, "CustomersByState") >= Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState") + (5 * ((Min(Fields!NYValue.Value, "CustomersByState")-Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState"))/6)) ,"#0ca102",
        Min(Fields!NEValue.Value, "CustomersByState") >= Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState") + (4  * ((Min(Fields!NYValue.Value, "CustomersByState")-Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState"))/6)) ,"#7fda24",
        Min(Fields!NEValue.Value, "CustomersByState") >= Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState") + (3  * ((Min(Fields!NYValue.Value, "CustomersByState")-Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState"))/6)),"#bdff30",
        Min(Fields!NEValue.Value, "CustomersByState") >= Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState") + (2  * ((Min(Fields!NYValue.Value, "CustomersByState")-Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState"))/6)),"Gold",
        Min(Fields!NEValue.Value, "CustomersByState") >= Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState") + ((Min(Fields!NYValue.Value, "CustomersByState")-
        Min(Fields!SDValue.Value, "CustomersByState"))/6),"Yellow",
        1=1,"Coral"
        )
```